# Felt like vomiting while working out in the Gym!

Tags: weightlifting, cardio, strength-training, gym, crossfit

While I was working out at the gym last week I felt like vomiting at the end.
I started with a 10 minutes cardio and then a 45 Minutes weight training session.
And finally, at the end I did sledgehammer smashes on a tire( 15 reps X 3 Sets ).

During the second set, I felt my gut out and got dizzy. I knew I was pushing myself hard but never felt this way earlier. Just after sipping some water I was back to normal. But I still want to know what had happened to my body during that time.

What could be the possible reasons for such behavior by my body?

Comment: Thanks a ton for your abrupt answer. If you could reach a point "the reason is most likely" after reading this. Then I suppose that was the only thing I was asking. What could be the possible reasons for such behavior?

Comment: CrossFit considers vomiting a badge of honor. Trashcans are often named "Pukey".

Comment: Thanks @Raditz_35 just got this slipped from my mind. Google gave the best answers at times!

Comment: @EricKaufman Only if you say so! :)

Comment: For me, the problem usually resolves itself when I turn my back to the mirror, but I'll assume you're better looking.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this in the past (and still do occasionally), and I put it down to three possible issues, fitness, food and water.

**Fitness**

If, as by your own admission, you're pushing yourself particularly hard during a set, then you may find that you work harder than your body's ability to supply oxygen to the muscles, which would result in you gasping for air and feeling dizzy if you can't get enough oxygen into your system (yes, this is a very over-simplified version of events, but it boils down to you working harder than your body can handle = dizziness).

**Food**

When you train and push yourself, your body pulls blood into the muscles to fuel them, pulling it from places like your stomach, where it is normally used for digestion. If your stomach / guts / intestines can't digest the food in it, wants to get rid of it so it doesn't sit and rot, and does so by trying to get rid of the food in the most expedient manner (pretty much the direct opposite to how it got in there in the first place).

Having said that, there is still food in your stomach that's trying to be digested, so your body is probably trying to keep some blood there for digestion, causing less to be available to fuel your muscles, which is why you're getting the nausea / dizziness.

(Again, over simplified explanation of body stuff, but you should get the general gist).

**Water**

You're not drinking enough / your salts / electrolytes are out of whack. I'm going to admit, I haven't read into the physiology of this, but I know from personal experience that going into a training session a little dehydrated can really screw you up. Make sure you've drunk enough beforehand and during.

Comment: This would be a great answer if you could add breathing into the mix. Those are common signs of holding breath during intense exercise as well.

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer. That is the best answer one could ever give. Clears most of my queries. I could connect myself to the food and fitness sections there. Such “over simplification “ was necessary to answer such simple question!  Thanks again!